# Running c program with node.js and getting the response

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am trying to get a secure "run-like" program in node.js that runs C programs. I understand that I must use a child process to achieve my goal... And I choose exec because it has a callback arguments:

exec.js

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

var options = {
    timeout: 100,
    stdio: 'inherit',
    shell: true,
}

exec('gcc teste.c -o teste', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    exec('./teste', options, (error,stdout,stderr)=>{
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);

        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return;
          }
    });  
});
```

teste.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int i;
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

this is the output I am getting:

```
stdout: Hello World

stderr:
exec error: Error: Command failed: ./teste
```

Someone knows why this is happening? 
There is a better way of doing that?
How can I really get timout working?

Thanks

Comment: @tadman The path it correct since the program does run, else there would be output to std out. Thassya Abreu can you try to add a return 0 to your c program? Edit: tadman was faster

Comment: That#s apparently not related to C.

Comment: @PatrickHollweck I did it: [picture](https://photos.app.goo.gl/hkoWYtnajHEimheo6)

Comment: @Thassya Abreu Your return type is still void, change it to int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your executable should return a zero value (no error) on success:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int i;
  printf("Hello World\n");

  return 0;
}
```

If it doesn't you may have a random value assigned and that indicates some kind of error.

Comment: Now is a good time to point out that, per the language definition, `main` is *supposed* to return `int`, not `void`.  The behavior of `void main()` is *undefined*.

Comment: I put "return 0" but the error message is still there... [picture](https://photos.app.goo.gl/hkoWYtnajHEimheo6)

Comment: It's worth checking `process.cwd()` to see if the executable is being generated where you expect it, and if not, to specify the full path to the target. That it's running and *still* producing an error is odd, though.